# How to declare constant values in class and still access them in bounded methods

Tags: python, class, class-method

I have a simple problem that I can solve, but I'd like to find a cleaner way to get to my point. Let me give an example:

```
class Example(object):

    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number
        self.constant = 4.0

    def mult(self):
        return self.number * self.constant
```

So, I have a bound method to my class that is called `mult`. My problem is I would like to get the `self.constant` out of the `__init__` part of the class as it would be independent from any instance of that class. I was thinking about something like:

```
class Example(object):

    constant = 4.0

    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def mult(self):
        return self.number * constant
```

which obviously doesn't work. I was reading lately on class methods, which appeared like a good hint, but the problem I get with that is that I can't refer to my `self.number` in my method.

Anybody with a good idea, beside fixing my `mult` method to `return self.number * 4.0` (my real problem is a bit more complex than that).

Comment: **TL;DR**: you still have to access class attributes on the instance (`self.constant`) or class (`Example.constant`).